# Mass edit option ---Unable to See the Lock and Pencil Icons on the Fields

Tags: list-view, case-object

Can any help me out ?

I have a requirement ,to give "Mass Edit " Option for users.I have the "Inline Edit" and "Enhanced list" checked.Basically When we have a the mouse cursor on the "case number" field it shows the lock icon and the pencil icon on the picklist field "priority".But I'm unable to See the icons on the fields and unable to "Mass Edit" .Any help very much appreciated[image: .]

Comment: @HomerJ,crop1645:Thanks for your response.I have different record types been used.The Mass edit option should be given only for internal users Say RDBA nd Support.I have  a Record Type as Support which is default used by all users.when i select the Filter by Owner as "All Cases " , Filter By Additional Fields as Case Record Type :"Support",Case Owner Alias :"Support" and Case Owner Alias :"RBDA".Select fields and Restrict Visiblity.What I'm doing is write or wrong.Any help very much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, you have to include record types in the list view filter in order to allow for inline editing.  Can you confirm you've included the appropriate record type for the list?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on enhanced editing](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=inline_editing_in_a_list.htm) states several reasons - the most likely one as @HomerJ states is the one I outlined in bold but the others are worth noting and filing away in your memory bank.

*Some standard fields don’t support inline editing. For example, `Case Status`, `Opportunity Stage`, `Opportunity Amount`, `Opportunity Quantity and`Lead Status`, and most Task and Event fields can only be edited from a record's edit page. For more information, see [Guidelines for Editing Records with the Inline Editor]*[2](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_inline_editing.htm&language=en_US).

**If your organization uses record types, inline editing with lists is only available when all of the records in the list are of the same record type.** *Therefore, you must specify a filter of Record Type equals X, where X is the name of a single record type (or blank for the master record type).*

*You can’t use inline editing on an enhanced list if your list view filter criteria contain an OR clause.
For lists of activities, you must specify an additional filter of either Task equals True (for tasks) or Task equals False (for events) for inline editing to be available.*

*If your organization is using Person Accounts:
You can't use inline editing to change Person Accounts from a Contact list. You can only inline edit them from an Account list.\
You can only use inline editing on contacts associated to business accounts by specifying an additional filter of Is Person Account EQUALS False in your list criteria.*